# Generating Editable Form Sections And Observing Their Input Values To Update Model

Tags: knockout.js

Trying to generate editable slide "modules" when the value of `numSlides` changes. When the user selects the number of slides, corresponding fieldset "modules" are generated and placed in view. However, I now wish to update my slide models when the user edits any of the corresponding fields within any of these generated "modules". Attempting to return an object  on `numSlides` change with a key whose value is a new observable does not seem to work.

JS:

```
function viewModel() {

    var self = this;

    self.updateSlide = function(n) {
        return {
            title: 'slide' + (n + 1),
            imageSrc: ko.observable('img.jpg')
        };
    };

    self.numSlides = ko.observable(3);

    self.slides = ko.computed(function() {
        s = [];
        for (var i=0; i<self.numSlides(); i++) {
            s[i] = self.updateSlide(i);
        }
        return s;
    });

}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

HTML:

```
<div id="generalinput">
    <label for="numSlides"># of slides:</label>
    <select id="numSlides" data-bind="value: numSlides, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select><br>
</div>

<div data-bind="foreach: slides">
    <fieldset data-bind="attr: { id: title }">
        <div>
            <label data-bind="attr: { for: title + '_imageSrc' }">Slide Image:</label>
            <input type="text" data-bind="attr: { id: title + '_imageSrc' }, value: imageSrc()"><br>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Perhaps I need to go about this differently in order to get things working? Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you give to the value binding the actual observable value (`imageSrc()`) rather than the observable reference (`imageSrc`). So your input should look like that:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="attr: { id: title + '_imageSrc' }, value: imageSrc" />
```

Here is a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jbbt2/